# REST route with optional date params

Tags: php, mysql, rest, date, slim

I have route that query's a mysql DB for print jobs

`http://api.com/prints/`

I would like to query for results based on date so ...

`http://api.com/prints/YYYY`

or

`http://api.com/prints/YYYY/MM`

or

`http://api.com/prints/YYYY/MM/DD`

But use the same `http://api.com/prints/` route. Each print has a `TIMESTAMP`.

Does anyone have a good example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On optional params, you need to use brackets:

```
$app->get('/prints(/:year)(/:month)(/:day)', function ($year = '', $month = '', $day = '') {
    printf('%s-%s-%s', $year, $month, $day);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a query parameter to achieve this, i.e.:

`http://api.com/prints?timestamp=YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: how would you handle the month and day missing?

Comment: If you needed to support that: `http://api.com/prints?year=YYYY`, `http://api.com/prints?year=YYYY&month=MM`, and `http://api.com/prints?year=YYYY&month=MM&day=DD`.

Comment: Okay, now I see you tagged this with PHP, mysql, and slim. IMO that's really not enough. You need to explain you're looking for a PHP solution in your question and/or subject. I thought you were asking a general REST approach question, because you tagged the question with 'rest'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in the current [official Slim documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Parameters):

```
$app->get('/prints(/:year(/:month(/:day)))', function ($year = null, $month = null, $day = null) {
    if ($day !== null) {
        // return daily overview resource
    } else if ($month !== null) {
        // return monthly overview resource
    } else {
        // return yearly overview resource
    }

    // return some error or (better) overview resource on available data / endpoints
});
```